# How to create call column from grand grand child :( laravel backpack

Tags: relationship, laravel-8, laravel-backpack

I have 4 table Projects -> Systems -> Requirements -> Subfunctions

All is 1-n

Can i call add Subfunction column into Project :( Tks u guys .

Here  is my Project Model :

```
public function systems(){
    return $this->hasMany(System::class,'project_id','id');
}

public function requirements(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(Requirement::class,System::class,null,'id');
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: At my ProjectController i wanted to have 3 column : 
Systems , Requirements , Subfunctions !
So i can create Systems & Requirements Column at through relationship :

$this->crud->addColumn([
            'label' => 'Systems',
            'type' => 'select',
            'entity' => 'systems',
            'model' => 'App\Models\System',
        ]);

And :

$this->crud->addColumn([
            'label' => 'Requirements',
            'type' => 'select',
            'entity' => 'requirements',
            'model' => 'App\Models\Requirement',
        ]);

Comment: And i want to create Sub_function to at Project list :( i wondering can i do it :( Have tried with inner join but i just mess it up :(